# Enum with some repeated values?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum which holds certain types together and certain fields for each type.

```
public enum Types {

A (1, A.class, "stringA" ), 
B (2, B.class, "stringB" ), 
C (3, C.class, "stringC" ),

C1(3, C1.class, "stringC" ),
C2(3, C2.class, "stringC" ),
C3(3, C3.class, "stringC" ),
.
.
D (4, D.class, "stringD" ),
E (5, E.class, "stringE" ),
F (6, F.class, "stringF" ),
.
.
.
.
private int type;
private Class<?> className;
private String longname;

private Types(int type, Class<?> className, String longName ) 
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.className = className;
        this.longName = longName;
    }

//..... getter, setters
// returns name from type passed
   public static Types getName(int type) {

        for (Types e : Types.values()) {
            if (type == e.type)
                return e;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now everything was fine until there was no duplicate keys for types. So `TypeC` has subtype `C1, C2..` thus have the same type value as `3`.

It has a method `getName()` which gives the type by iterating  the `values` of the enum.

Now  `C1, C2, C3...` all map to same type value 3.

Now to differentiate C types, I have another variable name `definition` only for `C` subtypes . So values of `definition` are:

```
C1 100
C2 101
C3 101
```

So to retrieve a unique element of the enum for type C, I need two values `type` and `definition` both.

I have thought two approaches:

Either to add a new field for the whole enum named `definition`, so this will lead to null value for other types except C.

Or to create a new enum for C subtypes and use that enum to get C subtype names instead of from `getName()`.

How to achieve this in the best possible way ?

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: I would suggest you to replace type field with your definition field and let A have 100, B have 200, etc. because you may want to have A1, A2, G7, Z9 - well, not really, but for the sake of extensibility, replacing type with definition completely is always better, unless you're upgrading an widely-used library.

Comment: I would suggest that you rename the method 'Types getName(int type)'. Could you please add some javadoc, so that we can understand what the method sould do? 
Is it something like 'Types getByTypeKey(int typeKey)'?

Comment: @TobiasOtto: Yes it is `getByTypeKey(int typeKey)`. 1-->A type, 2-->B type, 3 --> C type

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether your `Cx` enums are really of the same class as `A`, `B` etc. And this can't be answered without knowing your domain model.

Just from syntax, I'd probably make `Types` to hold `definition` and `type` fields, `definition` being the primary key. Then two constructors, one with both `definition` and `type`, the other just with `definition` (`type` be assigned the same value as `definition`). This is basically what you suggested with two fields, but instead of `null` for non-`Cx` just consider `definition` to equal `type`.

Comment: A, B, C, D are different types and C1, C2.. are of type C. And `definition` attribute is only for types `Cx`, so type cannot be assigned a value same as definition. And can you give an example how two constructors would work?